# SimpleExoPlayerView Visibility

Tags: android, visibility, exoplayer

I have created a app with recycleView listLayout ,which upon clicking a item will lead to a activity with SimpleExoPlayerView and textView.I want to hide SimpleExoPlayerView if there is no videoURL available(I am getting videoURL from JSON file.So there some list items with no videoURL.)

```
if (videoUrl == "") {
    playerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

But this is not working. Help me!

Answer (score 0):

Create two activities, one would have layout with SimpleExoPlayerView and second without it. Then launch activity without it is the Url is "".

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!
Issue is not with SimpleExoPlayerView,but with comparing strings.
The statement in the if statement gives false always (as Strings are Objects,though their data is same ,they are not equal).

`if (videoUrl.eqauls("")) {
    playerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}`
       this minor change solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(videoUrl)) {
}
```

I have updated my code as `TextUtils.isEmpty()` is preferred over `String.equals("")`